# Indexes in Django PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql

**MY MODEL**

Below is the code for my model

```
class Email_passwords(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=40)
    source = models.CharField(default='unknown', max_length=150)
    domain = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50)
    before_at = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=150)
    hash = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    ipaddress = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=50)
    phonenumber = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)

    class Meta:
            constraints = [
                models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['email', 'password', 'source'], name='email password source unique')
            ]
            index_together = [
                ("domain", "before_at"),
            ]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

I was expecting total 7 indexes on this table but when i checked in database i got like 17 are there by default indexes on the table

[As you can see by clicking here the indexes for the table created by above model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGC4B.png)

What i want is to perform search using one field at a time though table.This table my contains billions of record. I want to achieve the maximum performance.

Comment: Will you be inserting or updating rows into this table? Having so many indexes will affect write performance fairly significantly. You are getting 2 indexes for every `CharField` index, one for exact matches and one for like queries, there's an index for the id field, one for the `index_together` and one for the constraint

Comment: Will you always be searching only 1 field at a time? If you can search by multiple columns at a time then you can create a multi column index to improve performance

Comment: @Iain Shevington I will always be performing one field search at a time. Will not be performing update operation at all. But will be inserting alot of data. I am not using like queries can I delete them and if yes how?